# How can I get a database of valid URLs for my search engine?

Tags: c#, .net, dns, search-engine

I'm trying to make an Internet Search Engine for school, with no more than C# and the .NET framework. I need to download the HTML code of the pages I'm indexing.

Now all it takes is to have a list of valid URLs.

Since I don't have a database of valid URLs, I made a trial and error algorithm, which grows a string:

```
a, b, c.....
aa, ab, ac......
aaa, aab, aac......
aaaa, aaab, aaac......
aaaaa, aaaab, aaaac......
```

and then tries to concatenate with .com, .net or whatever. This is too inefficient.

I need a database with valid URLs. Do you know where I can get one?

I can't work out how to get them straight out of DNS - is this something that's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your own. Most search engines crawl pages and follow links to other pages.

You start with a known list (it doesn't have to be very big) then:

1. Access a page in your list
2. Find links on those pages
3. Add those links to your list
4. Go to 1

As for using DNS; it's not designed to query URLs, only hostnames. And, as far as I know, you can't get a list of every hostname from a DNS server unless you manage the server yourself.

Comment: The wisest answer I've got in months! This seems like the best alternative. I really appreciate your input here!

Comment: +1 for simplicity. In addition, you can write an algorithm that attempts to do an http get from public ip addresses. There are a finite amount of them (albeit, a lot), and not all of them will host http content, however, that is another way to scour the internet for new servers to add to the database.

Comment: @Cypher: Attempting an HTTP get from public IP addresses isn't terribly reliable. Many (perhaps most?) sites won't respond if the host header isn't correct. And of those that do, you often end up with duplicate content: one batch of content from the site's human-readable URL, and a duplicate batch from the IP address. My experience from running a large-scale crawler for several years, is that very little quality content is available from raw IPs. People who post content worth crawling overwhelmingly have a domain name.

Comment: @JimMischel: I agree completely. There is more that can/should be done, but given that my comment was only a comment, expanding on the details wasn't my intention. The overall concept is there.